# Removing HETATMs from PDB files

Tags: perl, python-3.x, bioinformatics

I want to remove the heteroatoms (HETATM)s from PDB text files that I have locally. I found a perl script that apparently needs a quick tweak to make it do what I want but I'm unsure of what that tweak is.

```
!#/usr/bin/env perl

open(FILE,"file.pdb");
@file=<FILE>;
foreach (@file){
if (/^HETATM/){
print $_,"\n";
}}
```

Also, if anyone has an existing perl or python script that they are OK with sharing, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: what is the script not doing when you run it?

Comment: I want it to remove the HETATMs from the PDB file. Instead it is just printing all HETATM lines in the text file.

Answer (score 1):

In R you can use the [Bio3D package](http://thegrantlab.org/bio3d/):

```
library(bio3d)

# read pdb
pdb <- read.pdb("1hel")

# make a subset based on TYPE
new <- trim.pdb(pdb, type="ATOM")

# write new pdb to disk
write.pdb(new, file="1hel_ATOM.pdb")
```

This can also be combined with various other selection criteria, e.g. chain id, residue number, residue name, etc etc:

```
# select ATOM records for chain A
n1 <- trim.pdb(pdb, type="ATOM", chain="A")

# select residue numbers 10 through 20
n2 <- trim.pdb(pdb, resno=10:20)
```

Answer (score 0):

In PERL Try this

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my $filename = "4BI7.pdb";
die "Error opening file" unless (open my $handler , '<' , "$filename");
open my $newfile, '>', "filename.pdb" or  die "New file not create";
while($_ = <$handler>){
    print $newfile "$_" unless /^HETATM.*/;
}
```

Comment: Some general hints, please format your code using proper indention to make it more readable. `use strict;` and `use warnings;` should also be applied. And use the three argument version of open with lexical filehandles and proper error handling `open my $filehandle , '<' , $filename or die "Cannot read '$filename': $!";`.

Comment: @dgw Thank you for you comment. See my edit thats enough or not?